# edit data on the sheet from master sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have a file that consists of 5 data related sheets and an additional master sheet. These master sheet has a functionality that retrieves the data from all sheets into master sheet based on the ID.

The flow of the code for now is:

```
Range().Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Sheets("mSheet").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

It does what I want in a simple way that it only shows the necessary data. What I ideally want is to have link between this data and actual sheet, so that once I retrieve data in the master sheet and perform any edit - this edit is made in the actual corresponding sheet.

Any idea and suggestion is appreciated.

Original partial VBA code:

```
Sheets("dSheet1").Select
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table").Range.AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=id
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy

Sheets("masterSheet").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Sheets("masterSheet").Range("A8")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will copy the contents of your selection, but instead of pasting the value will enter the reference to the cell, so when the cell gets updated, so would the master sheet:

```
Sub foo()
Range("A1").Select
Sheets("mSheet").Range("A2").Formula = "=" & Selection.Address
End Sub
```

**EDIT**

The following will do the opposite of the code above, so it will copy the data, paste it in your master Sheet and then go back to the original copied range and enter the cell reference there so when the master is updated, so is that range:

```
Sub foo()
Range("A1").Select 'select the range to be copied
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy 'copy it
Sheets("mSheet").Range("A2").PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues) 'paste the value into your master sheet
Range("A1").Formula = "=" & Sheets("mSheet").Range("A2").Address
'go back to your previous selection and enter the formula to reference the specific cell
End Sub
```

**UPDATE**

Replace your code with the following, as it does the same but with fewer lines of code an without any Select statement:

```
Sub foo2()
Sheets("dSheet1").ListObjects("Table").Range.AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=ID
Sheets("dSheet1").Range("A2:D2").Copy Destination:=Sheets("masterSheet").Range("A8")
'change the range above to copy as many columns as you need
End Sub
```

Then add the following code behind you Master Sheet to detect changes:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
'place this code behing the masterSheet
LastRow = Sheets("dSheet1").Cells(Sheets("dSheet1").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
'get the last row of dSheet1
If Target.Address = "$A$8" Then 'if A8 changes
For i = 1 To LastRow 'loop through dSheet1 to find the ID
    If Sheets("dSheet1").Cells(i, 3) = Range("C8").Value Then 'when ID found
    Sheets("dSheet1").Cells(i, 1) = Range("A8").Value 'change relevant cell with new data
    End If
Next i
End If

'below do the same as above to change data for other columns, add more to adapt it to be able to make changes to however many columns you are copying over
If Target.Address = "$B$8" Then
For i = 1 To LastRow
    If Sheets("dSheet1").Cells(i, 3) = Range("C8").Value Then
    Sheets("dSheet1").Cells(i, 2) = Range("B8").Value
    End If
Next i
End If

If Target.Address = "$D$8" Then
For i = 1 To LastRow
    If Sheets("dSheet1").Cells(i, 3) = Range("C8").Value Then
    Sheets("dSheet1").Cells(i, 4) = Range("D8").Value
    End If
Next i
End If
End Sub
```

This assumes that your ID's are unique and you are getting a single row as a result of your autofilter.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but probably we have a bit different understanding of master sheet. In my master sheet, I enter the ID of the item and get the related data from all original sheets into this master sheet. One item at the time. So, when I want to edit the data in the master sheet I want it to be edited in the original sheet as well. But, the master sheet is temporary, so to say I can lookup for one item, then later look for other. Is it more clear?

Comment: Ah, ok, in that case all you have to do is the opposite of what you did when getting the data into the master sheet once you edit anything, if you were to post into your question the actual code you are using to retrieve the data into your master sheet then I will be able to suggest a way to update the data in that specific sheet?

Comment: I've updated my answer and it works by detecting changes to the cells on your Master sheet then looping through dSheet1 to find the row with the ID on your Master sheet and then updates the values according to what was entered on your master sheet. Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

How about adding buttons.

CopyID - Copy range from SheetID = B1

After Editing, EditID - will clear range in SheetID = B1, and rewrites everything from mSheet Range from A3 then paste in SheetID = B1

[image]

Edit ID code:

```
Public Sub EditID(ID As String)
Sheets(ID).Select

If Range("A1").Value <> "" Then
Range("A1").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Clear
End If

Sheets("mSheet").Select

If Range("A3").Value <> "" Then
Range("A3").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Copy

Sheets(ID).Select
Range("A1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

End If

Sheets("msheet").Select

End Sub
```